# Is there any suggestion to avoid several "SaveChanges" in one transaction?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have some questions about ASP.NET Core.

Is there any suggestion to avoid  several "SaveChanges" in one transaction? So if I have ,for example an insert method for relational tables, and need to use first operations result in second operation
I must use `_context.SaveChanges()`. But I think it is not suitable for one transaction's logic.

For example:

```
using var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
try
{
    var firstModel = new FirstModel()
    {
         ////several property asignments
    }
    await _context.FirstModels.AddAsync(firstModel);
    await _context.SaveChanges();

    var secondModel = new SecondModel()
    {
         ////several property asignments
         FirstModelId = firstModel.Id;
    }
    await _context.SecondModels.AddAsync(secondModel);
    await _context.SaveChanges();
}
catch
{
    await transaction.RollbackAsync()
}
```

I think the SaveChanges after firstModel is not suitable to transaction logic. I want to avoid it.
Or maybe another suggestion to make one SaveChanges after all operations. I searched really a lot but can't find that maybe Entity Framework handles this by itself. Or is there any another logical issue?
Also I can't find MSSQL 'Inserted' or 'Deleted' tables in EF.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, use navigation properties. `SecondModel.FirstModel = firstModel`.

Comment: As for MSSQL 'Inserted' or 'Deleted' tables. They don't exist. They're temp tables that are accessible in triggers only.